# Heroku build failing on dependency install

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js, node-modules

Node Canvas isn't installing on Heroku build, even though it works just fine on my own PC. I'm on nodejs version 12.16.3. I can't find a solution for this anywhere.

Canvas is a must, and I've never seen this error before until Heroku. Is this a problem with Heroku or a problem with my package/package-lock files?

My Discord is Tom Becker#0590 in case you need it.

Here's my build log:

```
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  12.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.18.1...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.5
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       
       > deasync@0.1.19 install /tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/node_modules/deasync
       > node ./build.js
       
       `linux-x64-node-12` exists; testing
       Binary is fine; exiting
       
       > canvas@2.6.1 install /tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/node_modules/canvas
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
       
       Package pangocairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
       Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pangocairo.pc'
       to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
       No package 'pangocairo' found
       gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pangocairo --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
       gyp ERR! configure error 
       gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
       gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
       gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
       gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
       gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1073-aws
       gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=6" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
       gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/node_modules/canvas
       gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.1
       gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
       gyp ERR! not ok 
       node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
       node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=6 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
       node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
       node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
       node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
       node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
       node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1073-aws
       node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
       node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/node_modules/canvas
       node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.1
       node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
       node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
       Failed to execute '/tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/tmp/build_282e7f55032649968878bcdef8821199/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=6 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 1
       npm ERR! canvas@2.6.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
       npm ERR! Exit status 1
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@2.6.1 install script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.3BVoV/_logs/2020-06-26T16_20_37_894Z-debug.log

-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Package pangocairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
       Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pangocairo.pc'
       to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
       No package 'pangocairo' found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is some issue with prebuilt packages. It can work  depending on Node.js version, latest version which is worked for me is `14.14.0` so try to setup it in your `package.json`

- v12.0.x succeeds
- v12.16.x fails
- v12.x.x fails
- v13.0.x succeeds
- v13.3.0 succeeds
- v13.x.x fails
- v14.0.x fails
- v14.1.x fails
- v14.14.0 succeeds
- v15.0.1 fails

More about this here https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1563#issuecomment-625149050

I had similar issue after my builds switched from Node v14.14.0 to v15.0.1 after recent release https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v15.0.1/

Answer (score 0):

in addition to using a compatible `node.js` version (I'm using `13.3.0`), I did two other things:

- installed `node-pre-gyp` which seemed to pre-build everything correctly `npm install node-pre-gyp@7.1.2`
- set heroku stack to 18:
  `heroku stack:set heroku-18`